# how to specify a directory and a function with upload_to in django

Tags: python, django, image-upload, file-storage

I have 2 models cars and profiles:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=naming, null=True, blank=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles', null=True, blank=True)
```

I need the naming function but I also want the uploaded files to be in the folder cars instead of just in the media directory.

Is there any way to upload them into that folder AND call that function? 
In the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) I could only find one way but not both ways.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what do you mean upload & call the function at the same time, but the function is indeed called, otherwise it won't produce any paths. For your first question, you could do the following:

```
def naming(instance, file_name):                                                 
    model_name = instance.__class__.__name__
    return os.path.join(model_name, file_name)
```

Comment: right now the pictures I upload for profiles will be saved in `media/profiles` the pictures I upload in the cars will be uploaded to `media` but I want it to have in `media/cars`. If I use yours it get's stored like that however it's not in the database. If I do `print instance.image_file.path` I still see the old folder structure `/media/myfile.png`